# Pivot to identify same contract type in multiple cells

Tags: pivot-table, multiple-instances

Per attached example how can I use pivots to filter by all rows and columns with C01 and C02 contract for a unique client for example

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oc04S.jpg

Comment: Can you provide a mockup of the data in text form here in the question, rather than the image alone? Also, what research have you done and what have you tried?